Unique constraint that includes a column from a FK table
Given the following contrived table structures...
CREATE TABLE country (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE state (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  country_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_state_country
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
    REFERENCES country (id));

CREATE TABLE city (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  state_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT FK_city_state
    FOREIGN KEY (state_id)
    REFERENCES state (id));

...how can I create a UNIQUE constraint that prevents duplicate city.name values in a single country?
For example, if the following data exists...
Country



id
name




1
United States


2
Canada



State



id
country_id
name




1
1
Maine


2
1
Oregon


3
2
Ontario



City



id
state_id
name




1
1
Portland



...how could another Portland city in America (Oregon) be prevented, but a Portland city in Canada be permitted?

america  for example has some duplicate city names in different counties, so your approach is wrong from the start

As I said, the example is contrived.  These aren't the real tables or data for my problem but if I used those I feel that would create an extra layer of complexity to the explanation/problem that isn't necessary.

an extra layer will not work, you need to rewrite your tables.

What about Portland, Maine?

I suggest that your schema is over-normalized.

CREATE TABLE country (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE state (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  country_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (id, country_id), -- redundant but needed for the foreign key in city
  CONSTRAINT FK_state_country
    FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
    REFERENCES country (id));

CREATE TABLE city (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  state_id INT NOT NULL,
  country_id INT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY (country_id, name), -- enforces a unique city per country
  CONSTRAINT FK_city_state
    FOREIGN KEY (state_id, country_id)
    REFERENCES state (id, country_id));


Changing the schema as you've suggested is theoretically possible, but in my specific situation... awkward to say the very least...
Is there any way to implement uniqueness without changing the schema?

Also, with your solution, what if the state of Maine were to secede and become part of Canada?  :)    The update to achieve this would no longer be only for state.country_id, but also all cities associated with Maine, which is obviously less than ideal.

Make the foreign key cascade on update.

I'm not going to address your condition that you can't change the schema.

I'm angling, in the first instance, for solution that doesn't introduce duplication of data.
